# split number and string matlab

Tags: regex, string, matlab, split

Given a string `'12.39 ert_23::ex::status = 12'`. The format is always time followed by a string. I would like to split the time i.e `12.39` and the remaining string. I have used `regexp` but could not achieve what I need.

```
str_in = '12.39 ert_23::ex::status = 12';
str_out =  regexp(str_in,'\d+(\.\d+)? \w*','split');
```

the expected out is

```
str_out = '12.39'  ' ert_23::ex::status = 12'
```

Comment: If it always follows the same format, you could also hardcode it `str_out={str_in(1:5), str_in(7:end)};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach:

```
>> C = textscan(str_in, '%f %s', 'Delimiter','')
C = 
    [12.3900]    {1x1 cell}

>> celldisp(C)
C{1} =
   12.3900
C{2}{1} =
ert_23::ex::status = 12
```

Note that first part is parsed and returned as a number.

Comment: +1 This way you indeed avoid having [two problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
ind = regexp(str_in,'\d+(\.\d+)','end');
str_out = {str_in(1:ind), str_in(ind+1:end)};
```

Comment: Maybe it would be nice if the space was in the second part of the cell, instead of with the number.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
>> regexp(str_in,'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) (.*)','tokens', 'once')

ans = 

    '12.39'    'ert_23::ex::status = 12'

>>
```

Comment: add `regexp(.., 'tokens', 'once')` to get rid of the nested cells

Comment: also to be exact you have to make the fraction part of the number optional to match the OP regex pattern. You could use a non-capturing group: `regexp(str, '(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) (.*)', ...)`